# How to get delayed column values in dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have sensor data, the sensor's data format is (value, timestamp). I put the sensor value into DataFrame, the value of DataFrame is:

```
+-----+-------------+
|value|    timestamp|
+-----+-------------+
|    1|1493626740000|
|    7|1493626741000|
|    3|1493626743000|
|    5|1493626744000|
|    7|1493626746000|
|    9|1493626747000|
|    7|1493626748000|
|    9|1493626749000|
+-----+-------------+
```

The timestamp is ordered and the timestamp interval is different，I want to delay the value for one data point, this is my expect result:

[image]

What kind of operation should I do on the dataframe to accomplish this?

This is input code:

```
val arr = Array((1, 1493626740000L), (7, 1493626741000L), (3, 1493626743000L), (5, 1493626744000L), (7, 1493626746000L), (9, 1493626747000L), (7, 1493626748000L), (9, 1493626749000L))
    var df= sc.parallelize(arr, 4).toDF("value","timestamp")
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not too sure what you're looking for. Can you please explain your question some more? Thanks.

Comment: I hava changed my question @ Sohum Sachdev

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag` function available in spark with an offset of 1. Using your example data:

```
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("timestamp")
val defaultValue = df.head.getAs[Int]("value")

val df1 = df.withColumn("valueDelay", lag("value", 1, defaultValue).over(w))
df1.show()

+-----+-------------+----------+
|value|    timestamp|valueDelay|
+-----+-------------+----------+
|    1|1493626740000|         1|
|    7|1493626741000|         1|
|    3|1493626743000|         7|
|    5|1493626744000|         3|
|    7|1493626746000|         5|
|    9|1493626747000|         7|
|    7|1493626748000|         9|
|    9|1493626749000|         7|
+-----+-------------+----------+
```

If you know the first value will always be 1, you can skip finding the value in the first row and only set the default value for `lag` to 1 (it's only used for the first row in this case).

Hope it helps!

Comment: @mentongwu That is true, if you have one or more columns with values you can split into different partitions you can add `.partitionBy(columns)` to the `Window`. Otherwise to perform this kind of operation you have to use a single partition. If your dataframe is not very big it should not be an issue.

Comment: My dataframe is very big,the each partition's first value is error even through I use .partitionBy(columns),the first partition's first row could be 1,but the second partition's first row should be the the first partition's last row

Comment: @mentongwu By `partitionBy(columns)` I meant you need to have a third (or more) column to do the partitioning by. As far as I know, to use the last row as value for another partitions first row is not possible in spark. You could try to use `.coalesce(1)` on the dataframe before using `lag` and see how long it takes.